# $_POST is array, how do I get content

Tags: php, arrays, post

`$_POST['field']` is array. I want get the information out. `$title = $_POST['field'][0]`

```
print_r($_POST['field']);
// OUTPUT

array (
[field_title] => Title
[field_link] => http://www.example.com/
)
```

Comment: Worth reading the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to see why arrays actually are ordered maps with key/value associations. You can have numerical indexes, like a typical array, but an associative array won't automatically have a numerical index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an associative array which means you cannot use numerical indices. Just refer to it by it's key:

```
$title = $_POST['field']['field_title']
```

Comment: Of if OP truly does want the `0th` index, they can access it like this: `$title = reset($_POST['field']);`. Or they could retrieve the array's values into a numerical array like: `$fields = array_values($_POST['field']); $title = $fields[0];`